# How to fix folder presentation in Intellij Idea Ultmate 2018.02 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed Intellij Idea 2018.02 Ultimate on Ubuntu 18.04. My folders like "0.7.0" is being showed as "0" in project structure as shown in screencopy. I tryed to setup any options but no result. [image]

Comment: Does it happen in the release version? Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: 2018.2 EAP Build #IU-182.2574.2

Comment: The question was if it's a regression in the EAP build.

Comment: Ok. Wait release version. Thanks

Comment: Does it happen in 2018.1.4 release available at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html? If this issue is a regression and is specific to 2018.2 EAP, please report a bug in YouTrack with the logs/sample project. Thank you.

Comment: The problem was solved after regression to 2018.1.4 release version. Thanks